# Unix time stamp formatting

Tags: php, time, unix-timestamp

for some reason this is giving me an odd time:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$todaysdate = date('d-m-y h:i:s a', time());
$todaysdatestring = strtotime($todaysdate);
```

This is returning me a time in 2018.

e.g. 1515889804

It appears to be setting the time as Month / Year / Date.

Which i cant understand...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve here, but if you change `d-m-y h:i:s a` to `d-m-Y h:i:s a`, it will give you the correct date.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$todaysdate = date('d-m-Y h:i:s a', time());
$todaysdatestring = strtotime($todaysdate);
```

but if you want to get the current timestamp, why don't you simply use `time()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$todaysdate = date('m/d/y h:i:s a', time());
$todaysdatestring = strtotime($todaysdate);

var_dump(time(), $todaysdate, strtotime($todaysdate));
```

I changed "d-m-y" to "m/d/y".

I don´t know the exact terminology and ISO standards for time and dateformats but 
in Eclipse it said strtotime wants an "English Dateformat".

PHP Version 5.3.28

Comment: The PHP manual summary is a bit misleading. If the separator is slashes then strtotime assumes an american format, if the separator is dashes or dots then strtotime assumes a European format. The English use both slashes and the European format.

Answer (score 0):

When `strtotime()` function parses your datetime string `18-01-14 01:00:44 am`, it assumes that number 18 is year, 01 month and 14 day (format `Y-m-d`); thats why you get unix timestamp for year 2018. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) what date formats does function `strtotime()` understand.

To check how `strtotime()` function parses datetimes, see [`date_parse()`](http://php.net/manual/function.date-parse.php) function, like: `print_r(date_parse($todaysdate));`. <kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/91365)</kbd>

If you wish to convert unknown format to timestamp use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`:

```php
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y h:i:s a', '18-01-14 01:00:44 am');
echo $dt->getTimestamp(); # or $dt->format('U');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/91364)</kbd>